# ObjC: How to proper implement a class that release itself?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, memory-management

I'm implementing a Login view and I need this view to be show at any time in my app. So to make it easier I create a class method called showLogin and when the view closes I want it to release itself so I did this:

```
@implementation LoginController

@synthesize releaseOnClose;

+ (void)showLogin {
     LoginController *login = [[LoginController alloc] init];
     login.releaseOnClose = YES;
     [login show]; // Potential leak of login object
}

- (id)init {
     if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]) {
          releaseOnClose = NO;
     }
     return self;
}



- (void)show {
     if (self.view.superview == nil) {
          // show the view
     }
}



- (void)btnCloseTouched {
     [self.view removeFromSuperview];
     if (releaseOnClose) {
          [self release];
     }
}
```

The Static Analyzer is telling me that there's a potential leak on showLogin, but in fact there isn't because I release the object in btnCloseTouched (don't worry about other features of a login view, for now it just open and close).

So I'd like to know how to avoid this potential leak message and how to proper implement this kind if class method to handle correctly the memory?

**The Idea**

A little more about what I thought. I wanted to call showLogin and it would exists until it's closed without the caller having to manage the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's complaining about a leak is because you're allocating memory which is not released - for example:

```
LoginController *login = [[LoginController alloc] init];
```

And the way you're doing this seems all backwards - not really sure why you're instantiating a new object of LoginController within itself, and then releasing self in the attempt to release the new object? There has to be a much better way of doing it.

You'll have to release the instance of that one you allocated - self is not the instance of the new one you allocated (login).

Do the following when you're done with it:

```
[login release];
```

Comment: I don't get the second part. self in btmCloseTouched is the correct instance. Agree on the other parts, though.

Comment: self != LoginController *login = [[LoginController alloc] init]; though. It may be the correct instance for the object containing 'login', but it's not the same instance. Anyways, the code is really confusing as it is - it's flawed.

Comment: @xil3 it looks like the class method tells an instance to display, and then the instance receives the action to close (and release).  It's definitely weird, but it seems workable.

Comment: @Richard yeah, it releases itself, but the new login object it allocated memory for doesn't get released. I understand what you're saying though - the login object is a new instance of the same class, which should in turn release itself. I suppose there is a possibility that it would work, but it's prone to fail. There are many more easy ways to do this.

Comment: @xil3 +showLogin is acting like a factory here; it is a *class method* so the only LoginWindow object around is the one that will receive the `btnCloseTouched` message and release itself.  But again, there are much easier ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll rethink this approach it's not natural and much error prone. My original idea was to simply the use of the login view.

Comment: A little more about what I thought. I'd call showLogin and it would exists until it's closed without the caller having to manage the instance.

Answer (score 1):

in your @implementation block you can declare the LoginController class like this:

```
@implementation LoginController

@synthesize releaseOnClose;

LoginController *mySingleLoginController;
```

then in your class method you can do:

```
+ (void)showLogin {
     mySingleLoginController = [[LoginController alloc] init];
...
```

However as a design choice i wouldn't recommend this approach ...

Moszi

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a new class for the login window (`LoginView`) and then make sure that the class cleans up after itself in `dealloc`. Then you can make a new instance of that class when you need it, and when you remove it there should be no memory leak.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you suggestion but I don't think this is the problem. All dealloc are ok, the analyzer is telling that there's a potential leak because by convention every alloc needs a release and it can't find the release (which is in btnCloseTouched). I'm not sure if I implementing this kind of class correctly.

Comment: I meant that you should make a separate class for the login window, then when you need to show it, create an instance, add it to your view, then release it. When you remove it from your view, it's memory will be taken care of in `dealloc`. It seems like a more regular way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it the ordinary way and let the instance that initialized the class release it, or put it in an autorelease pool?

I don't see the benefit of having a class that removes and releases itself when some action happens. What's your motivation for doing it this way?

Comment: I was thinking in simplifying things, but I'm changing my mind as others said it's error prone.